# JSONWithPadding Jersey 1.x + jquery

Tags: java, jquery, jersey, jsonp, jersey-1.0

Hello I 'm trying to make a rest call from jquery into a jersey 1.18 server using jsonp

```
@GET
@Path("jsonp")
@Produces("application/x-javascript")
public JSONWithPadding testJSONP(@QueryParam("callback") String callback){
    String retVal="YES";
    return new JSONWithPadding( new GenericEntity<String>("{\"test\":\"" + retVal + "\"}"){},callback);
}
```

and the jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:9280/manager/jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    success: function(data){
        console.log("success");
        alert(data.test);
    }
});
```

ALthough, it seams that JSONWithPadding is not functioning properly, firefix's console returns:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement                                  jsonp:1
```

the content of the jsonp is:

```
{
   "callbackName":"jQuery111109478052598614781_1410424986004",
   "jsonSource":{
         "rawType":"java.lang.String",
         "type":"java.lang.String",
         "entity":"{\"test\":\"YES\"}"}
}
```

Any help :) ?

Comment: solved by com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.JSONPObject instead of JSONWithPadding